# Show dimension of dual space $V'$ equals dimension of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

There is this answer which very intuitively answers the question:

[Dual space of finite dimensional space V has the same dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820014/dual-space-of-finite-dimensional-space-v-has-the-same-dimension)

But I would appreciate help with Axler's proof (3.95) on page 101 of "Linear Algebra Done Right", 3rd ed. There he gives a one liner referring to a prior result: Dimension of $\mathcal L(V,W) =(\dim V)(\dim W)$. I am puzzeled how to apply this as we know $\dim V$, but we are trying to determine, in this case, $\dim W$.

So how do we know $\dim \mathcal L(V,W)$ a priori?

Thanks

Comment: Showing $\dim L(V,W)=\dim V\dim W$ amounts to the same proof as given at your link, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947163/show-that-diml-w-mn). So proving $\dim V'=\dim V$ this way is again a duplicate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde If I understand your link, it is ostensibly the same as the link I provided. But in the context of your comment and my question, we have: $\dim \mathcal L(V,V')= (\dim V)(\dim V')$. We know $\dim V$, but how do we know what to use for $V'$ on the LHS. Thanks. With regards,

Comment: This is not what we do - see the answer below. We put $W=K^1$, the $1$-dimensional vector space over $K$, and not $W=V'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V$ is a $K$-vector space, then $V' = \mathcal{L}(V,K)$ by Definition. As $K$ is a $1$-dimensional $K$-vector space, you get $$\dim V' = \dim \mathcal{L}(V,K) = \dim(V)\dim(K) = \dim(V).$$